# overflow visible: hidden by parent (position:relative)

Tags: css, html, position, overflow, absolute

```
.product {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:visible;
}

.menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
}

<div class="product">
    <div class="menu></div>
</div>
```

The menu is hidden by its parent product. The product overflow is visible.
How to make the menu fully visible? The product position is relative, which can
not be changed.

The menu is hidden, and it will become visible on mouseover.

EDIT ---------

The above code is working. The menu is not fully visible because it is clipped by next product. So set z-index to 1000. However,

```
.product {
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:visible;
  }
```

is not working. There is a vertical scroll, same as overflow-y:auto. why?

Comment: Well, the above code already does what you ask...

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding or margins to them if it's just underneath it. However it's kind of hard to actually see what it's doing so maybe make a fiddle.

```
.product {
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:200px;
padding: 10px;
overflow:visible;
}

.menu {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:400px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The menu is hidden, and it will become visible on mouseover.

Comment: So what is your question? When the menu becomes visible on mouseover it isn't fully there? like it's underneath the product?